AirBus A380 and Boeing 747 - fuel consumption while taking off?
I have talked with my friends about fuel consumption while taking off. None of us know much about airplanes, so I'm asking here, because I didn't find an answer searching on the internet.
How much fuel does a big airplane like an Airbus A380 or a Boeing 747 consume per second/minute during take-off?
Let's suppose that it is fully loaded and uses full power.

What do you mean by "takeoff"? When the wheels leave the ground (liftoff)? When the aircraft reaches some altitude? (it takes the same quantity of fuel to liftoff as to reach 1500 ft)

This video shows the A380 engine instruments during takeoff. There are differences between engines but they average about 8700 kg/hr per engine, or 34,800 kg/hr total (9.7 kg/s, or 12.1 L/s, or 3.2 gal/s). This analysis lists takeoff from start of ground roll to rotation as using 597 lb and taking 28 seconds (for a full power takeoff). Doing the math on this comes out to 34,816 kg/hr, which is extremely close to the values in the video. The 75% flex takeoff values come out to 25,353 kg/hr (7 kg/s).
I didn't find any great information about the 747, but the 747-8 engines have about 85% of the thrust of the A380 engines, and scaling the fuel consumption based on that gives 8.3 kg/s, 10.3 L/s, 2.7 gal/s.

With a quite good approximation it can be shown that a jetliner typically consumes fuel for around 3% of its MTOW during warmup, taxing and take off. This percentage corresponds to around 17'250kg for an A380 and 13'431kg for a B747-8.
Another 1.5% of MTOW is consumed in fuel during the climb phase.

Values for the A380.
